# 兄弟要素がない場合、CSSかJavascriptで指定要素を非表示にできますか？

Tags: javascript, html, css

現在のhtml

```
<main>
  <h2>あ</h2>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <h2>い</h2>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</main>
```

h2タグに続くタグがsectionタグでなければh2タグを非表示にしたい。
上のsectionタグがない場合

```
<main>
  <h2>い</h2>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</main>
```

上下いずれもsectionタグがない場合

```
<main>
</main>
```

---

元のhtmlについては、sectionタグ部分以外については、ある程度変更可能です。
変更可能なhtml案。

```
<main>
  <div id='hoge'>
    <h2 id='hogeh2'>あ</h2>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </div>
  <div id='piyo'>
    <h2 id='piyo2'>い</h2>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [`:has()`疑似クラス](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/:has)で条件付けできます。
- [`+`次兄弟結合子](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator)で直後の要素について指定できます。
- [`:not()`疑似クラス](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/:not)で条件を否定できます。

これらを組み合わせることで「直後に`section`要素が登場しない`h2`要素」という条件付けされたスタイル定義が可能です。

```css
h2:not(:has(+ section)) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>あ</h2>
  <section>1</section>
  <h2>い</h2>
  <h2>う</h2>
  <section>4</section>
  <h2>え</h2>
</main>
```

なお、`:has()`疑似クラスは2023/12/19にリリースされたFirefox 121にて主要ブラウザーでの対応が出そろいました。